# How to output only a part of values from ListBox?

Tags: c#

I would like to output only a part of items from `listBox1` like:`response.response.items[counter].first_name` to `lable_name.Text`. How can I do that?

Part of method:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < response.response.items.Count; counter++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(response.response.items[counter].first_name + " " + response.response.items[counter].last_name  + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

The way I output items to lable:

```
private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = listBox1.Items.Count -1;

    for (int counter = count; counter >= 0; counter--)
    {
        if (listBox1.GetSelected(counter))
        { 
            lable_name.Text= listBox1.Items[counter].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: string name = listbox1.Items[counter].ToString().Split(' ')[0] could be one of the options ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lable_name.Text = listbox1.Items[counter].ToString().Split(' ')[0];
```

could be one of the options ...

just make sure what charackter are qou spliting on as well as the text in string.